# Should I be concerned about tin plating flaking off aluminum bus in electric panel?

Tags: electrical-panel

I'm doing some renovations on an old house and noticed that the tin plating on the busbar of the electric panel is coming off (picture below). There's also rust at the bottom of the panel, so I figured water was getting in, and on further investigation I found that the duct seal on the SEU cable going into the meter pan was all cracked.

I'm going to replace the duct seal to correct the issue, but I was wondering how much of an issue is the loss of the tin plating - enough to consider replacing the panel?

Also, should I be worried about corrosion inside the meter pan? I can't get in there to see what's going on.

[image: Tin plating flaking off]

[image: another picture]

Comment: Weird. Why there exactly, why does it look like it's radiating from a particular bus stab?  Is it similar on the other stab? (the breakers easily rock out).   This suggests "overheat event".

Comment: What's with the melty bits on the neutral bar?  More "overheat event" evidence?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I added another photo with more breakers removed and it does look like it's radiating from one stab; would I then want to avoid using that space in the panel?

Comment: This is one of those questions that's mostly a matter of opinion but will get giant votes for whoever says it in an answer first: This looks dangerous and I wouldn't want it in my house.

Comment: I'm seeing corrosion on the breaker case screws.  Could be water damage.

Comment: The “melty” stuff looks more like anti-oxide paste that’s been dripping out with water, maybe mixed with some rust.